# Using Dataloader to display an image

Tags: pytorch

I have successfully loaded my data into DataLoader with the code below:

```
train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(train_dataset, 32, shuffle=True)
```

I am trying to display a multiple images using the code below:

```
examples = next(iter(train_loader))
for label, img  in enumerate(examples):
    print(img.shape) # [32, 3, 224, 224]
```

How would I print each image in the batchsize using plt.imshow, as well as show the label? (Note: This is the CatDogDataset)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(train_dataset, 32, shuffle=True)

examples = next(iter(train_loader))

for label, img  in enumerate(examples):
   plt.imshow(img.permute(1,2,0))
   plt.show()
   print(f"Label: {label}")
```

Reference
https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/basics/data_tutorial.html